# C++ access class private attribute friend funcion with (void * callerobj) parameter

Tags: c++

I have a class called sender with private attribute isSending and a friend function sending. Inside the friend function, I want to access the isSending attribute

```
class sender{
    private:
    isSending=false;
    friend void* sending (void * callerobj);
}

void* sending (void * callerobj){
    while(<isSending is true>){

    }
}
```

I've tried

```
callerobj->isSending
callerobj.isSending
```

But I got compile error. How can I access isSending from a friend function with (void * callerobj) parameter?

Comment: try replacing `void` with `sender` in definition and prototype of `sending` function. or if you use c++11 use `auto` instead of `void`. or you can also cast the `void*`  to the object of type  `sender*`.

Answer (score 2):

Since the type of `callerobj` is `void*`, you cannot use it to access any member data or member function. After all, the original object could be an `int*`.

If you are sure that the original object is a `sender*`, you can cast `callerobj` to `sender*` and then use it to access its member data.

```
sender* senderobj = reinterpret_cast<sender*>(callerobj);
if ( senderobj != nullptr )
{
   while ( senderobj->isSending )
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since compiler doesn't know what `void*` is I mean is it `sender*` or any thing else compiler doesn't know that. So it can't access the `isSending`

try replacing `void*` with `sender*` in definition and prototype of `sending` function. or if you use c++11 use `auto*` instead of `void*`. or you can also cast the `void*` to the object of type `sender*`.

**Note: You'll have to be sure the `callerObj` is of type `sender*`**

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way, combining (ugh) reinterpret_cast and dynamic_cast. In general, void* is seldom necessary in modern C++, use e.g. auto or other language mechanisms to avoid the C-style type unsafety.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class Base
{
public:
    virtual void a_virtual_fcn() = 0;
};

// Need to inherit from Base to get real run-time cast below                                                                                                                                                                                 
class SomeClass : public Base
{
public:
    SomeClass() : is_sending(false) {}
    void a_virtual_fcn() {}
private:
    bool is_sending;

    friend int main();
};

int main()
{
    SomeClass sc;

    void* vp = &sc;

    if ( dynamic_cast<SomeClass*>(reinterpret_cast<Base*>(vp)) ) {
        cout << "is sending " << sc.is_sending << '\n';
    }

    return 0;
}
```